# Realme 11 pro fix application list anomaly

Tags: applications, malware, realme

Basically I find an app list anomaly, and don't know how to fix it, nor if it's the symptom of a compromise, or just an anomaly; here are the details:

A few month ago I bought a brand new phone (a Realme Pro 11) that was exposed in the store's display window. So even if theoretically not used by anyone, it was out of the package.

Now I find an anomaly in app list, and don't know what to think (after purchase I reset the device for security reasons, but maybe it was not enough).

In app list Google Assistant appears twice, and I find an app with a name "nessuno" that in my language mean "none" (and I can't uninstall it). The app "none" persist after many reboot.

So I am quite concerned, because even if I didn't installed any third party app except Google's app or AV app (after reset), maybe my device was already compromised in the store. To be fair AV app executed onto device (without rooting the device) didn't find anything, but I am afraid that maybe someone with physical access to device (in the store) may have installed some rootkit that is difficult to spot.

Here the screen of anomaly in app list I talked about

[image]

[image]

--Edited : adding detail

Two Google assistant app are the following packages

1. app:Google Assistant
   package:com.android.hotwordenrollment.xgoogle
   Launcher:null
2. app:Google Assistant
   package:com.android.hotwordenrollment.okgoogle
   Launcher:null

While no name app is :
app:Nessuno
package:com.android.systemui.overlay.fingerprint.anim.none
Launcher:null

Comment: You need to find out the app package name. Some app listing tools can do that. Once you have the packageName you can download it to a PC and analyze it's signature to see if it belongs to the system firmware.

Comment: @Robert thanks for information. I think I found the package name, the more concerning seems related to Oppo, so probably legit after all. I will download on pc to better analyse it. Thanks again (ps added details to original question)